# Bootstrap: Clearfix div takes unexpected height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When creating a new row after the masthead div the new row's columns would shrink: [image]

To encounter this issue I put a div.clearfix, that helped to get the row's columns in one line but now it creates an unexpected height out of nowhere:
[image]

Comment: I have created a codepen as well to demonstrate the problem: http://codepen.io/amigoo/pen/grKRyG

Comment: SO encourage people using their own live code editor. And I recommend you to add that in your question.

Comment: i think problem here .home #masthead { height: 100vh;}

Comment: @LaljiTadhani how? I have tried changing it but it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add #masthead CSS like this to make clearfix working his job:

```
.home #masthead {
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Did the job! Thanks

Comment: Any idea why it happened?

Comment: It happend cause 100vh property which made 219px empty space for clearfix, so you need to make clearfix to work what it must work, delete floats, so float: left, or right do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can write down below code for clear fix

```
.clearfix{
  line-height:0px;
  font-size:0px;
  height:0px;
}
```

Comment: Not working! Like I mentioned in my question it makes the columns "stretch".

Comment: Now try!  i have checked on your code pan link or just you can put height:0px in clearfix class

Comment: No, still not working and that's not what I am looking for.. :-)